# List of enabled GPS providers same as list of disabled GPS providers

Tags: android, location, android-gps

I have a Google Pixel C tablet running Android 7.1.1 with no SIM card connected to the internet with WiFi.  I've set the following permissions in my Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

and I am requesting permission from the user with:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]  {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
```

when I list the enabled and disabled GPS providers, the list is identical:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

List<String> providersEnabled = locationManager.getProviders(true);
LogHelper.d("location", "Enabled GPS providers:");
for (String providerEnabled:providersEnabled)
    Log.d("location", providerEnabled);

List<String> providersDisabled = locationManager.getProviders(false);
Log.d("location", "Disabled GPS providers:");
for (String providerDisabled:providersDisabled)
    Log.d("location", providerDisabled);
```

Enabled GPS providers:

- passive
- network

Disabled GPS providers:

- passive
- network

Is this an Android bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: getProviders docs + [enabled are subset of all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for `getProviders()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders(boolean)), the parameter is:

> boolean: if true then only the providers which are currently enabled are returned.

So, your first check returns only the enabled providers. Your second check returns **all** providers, regardless of whether they are enabled or not. Since both providers are enabled, they appear in both lists.